# Why is the code in my DevTools sources tab cut off?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

**Steps:**

- Put debugger in code
- Run Code
- Chrome stops at debugger

Note: I believe sometimes you have to refresh the screen or have multiple debuggers to see.

See Image[image]

Comment: Do you still see this behavior when you run Chrome in Incognito Mode?

Comment: @KayceBasques yes